# Swif4.0 accessing array of dictionary in easy and Swifty way

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I am just started to learn Swift and am new to ios development too.

```
var bookArray:[String:[[String:String]]] = ["book1":[["bookid":"SCIENCE","viewed":"12"],["bookid":"MATHS","viewed":"25"]],"book2":[["bookid":"HISTORY","viewed":"10"]]]
```

I will get the input as outer dictionary key and inner dictionary key, need to check and update dictionaries.

(i.e)

1. If the given outer dictionary key is "book1" and inner dictionary key is "MATHS" then the required output to be

   ```
   bookArray:[String:[[String:String]]] = ["book1":[["bookid":"SCIENCE","viewed":"12"],["bookid":"MATHS","viewed":"26"]],"book2":[["bookid":"HISTORY","viewed":"10"]]]
   ```

   (viewed count to be incremented)
2. If the given outer dictionary key is "book1" and inner dictionary key is "CHEMISTRY" then the required output to be

   ```
   bookArray:[String:[[String:String]]] = ["book1":[["bookid":"SCIENCE","viewed":"12"],["bookid":"MATHS","viewed":"25"],["bookid":"CHEMISTRY","viewed":"0"]],"book2":[["bookid":"HISTORY","viewed":"10"]]]
   ```

   (New Bookid to be added for the given outer key with viewed count as zero)

I started to work, but there was lot of complications with `for` loop and too many confusions...

Can some one suggest me some better way to accomplish the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following code can help you get it to the final answer.

```
 var myDict : [String:[[String: String]]] = [:]

 myDict = ["book1": [["bookid":"SCIENCE","viewed":"12"],  ["bookid":"MATHS","viewed":"25"]], "book2":[["bookid":"HISTORY","viewed": "10"]]]


func updateKey(_ outKey: String, _ innerKey: String){

var array = myDict[outKey] ?? []


if let index = array.firstIndex(where: {$0["bookid"] == innerKey}){
array[index]["viewed"] =  "\(Int(array[index]["viewed"]!)! + 1)"
}
else {
array += [["bookid":innerKey,"viewed":"0"]]
}

myDict[outKey] = array
}

 updateKey("book1", "MATHS")
 print(myDict)

 // ["book2": [["viewed": "10", "bookid": "HISTORY"]], "book1": [["viewed": "12", "bookid": "SCIENCE"], ["viewed": "26", "bookid": "MATHS"]]]

 updateKey("book1", "CHEMISTRY")
 print(myDict)

 //["book2": [["viewed": "10", "bookid": "HISTORY"]], "book1": [["viewed": "12", "bookid": "SCIENCE"], ["viewed": "26", "bookid": "MATHS"], ["viewed": "0", "bookid": "CHEMISTRY"]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a struct for `Book`

```
struct Book {
   let bookID: String
   let viewed: Int
}
```

and holding an array of that. Will be easier to manage.

Your array will change to:

```
var bookArray: [String:Book] = [Book(bookID: "SCIENCE", viewed: 12)]
```

You can create more books and add them to the array

Comment: Thanks for the reply let me try and let you know

Comment: Your answer is not clear to me as my object is type of dictionaries holding array of dictionaries. Not able to understand, something more clear with just an example or any references.